# How to map XML elements to multiple ranges of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

I need some help with something I am working on. What I want to ask is how can I map one XML element to multiple ranges of cells in Excel? I have tried multiple ways but none of them worked. Every way resulted in selecting the whole table column but not the ranges that I wanted.

My task is to by given .xsd file I need to firstly import it to a given excel file, then map the elements to the corresponding cells in the excel table.

This is the relevant part of the .xsd file.
[xsd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwZQu.png)

Here is a screenshot as well of the Excel file I need to map the specific ranges of cells. I want to know how to map for this picture two ranges, specifically: D8:D9, D11:D27

[excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX6Cy.png)

The rules in the document that I was given are:

Element < Podaci > need to include following elements:

```
<Podaci>
      <VrstaUlaganja>
      <MinimalniJamstveniFond>
      <JamstveniFond>
      <OstvareniProcenat>
</Podaci>
```

Number of element repetitions: The  element must appear 19 times in the  element i.e. for each code defined by the type_VrstaUlaganja enumerator in the 2U-K-F.xsd scheme.

The  element must not be repeated (duplicated) more than once for the same code.

The test file of XML what the output should look like when exporting the XML from the Excel so the students can check did they finish mapping the elements correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLObrazac>
  <PodaciDrustva>
    <JIBDrustva>4200213140004</JIBDrustva>
    <Dokument>
      <OvlasteniAktuar>OvlasteniAktuar1</OvlasteniAktuar>
      <Direktor>Direktor1</Direktor>
      <MjestoPodnosenja>MjestoPodnosenja1</MjestoPodnosenja>
      <DatumPodnosenja>1900-01-01</DatumPodnosenja>
    </Dokument>
  </PodaciDrustva>
  <Obrazac>
    <Dio1PeriodSifra>
      <NaDan>2017-12-31</NaDan>
      <SifraObrasca>2U-K-F</SifraObrasca>
    </Dio1PeriodSifra>
    <Dio2Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>01</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>0</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>0</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>0.00</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>02</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>1</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>2</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>3.00</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>03</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>-792281</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>-7922</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>-792281</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>04</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>7922</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>79228</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>792281625</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>05</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>0</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>0</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>0.9</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>07</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>2</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>2</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.1</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>08</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>-79228</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>-7922</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>-79228</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>09</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>7922</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>7922816</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>7922816</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>10</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>-1</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>-1</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>0.8</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
      <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>11</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>12</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>20</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>14</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>15</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>16</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>21</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>22</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>4</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>5</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>6.0</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>18</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
 <Podaci>
        <VrstaUlaganja>19</VrstaUlaganja>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>3</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>3</JamstveniFond>
        <OstvareniProcenat>1.2</OstvareniProcenat>
      </Podaci>
    </Dio2Podaci>
    <Dio3PodaciUkupnoCL31>
      <PodaciUkupnoCL31>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>7</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>8</JamstveniFond>
      </PodaciUkupnoCL31>
    </Dio3PodaciUkupnoCL31>
    <Dio4PodaciUkupno>
      <PodaciUkupno>
        <MinimalniJamstveniFond>9</MinimalniJamstveniFond>
        <JamstveniFond>10</JamstveniFond>
      </PodaciUkupno>
    </Dio4PodaciUkupno>
    <Dio5JamFond>
      <JamFond>
        <UkupnoJamstveniFond>11</UkupnoJamstveniFond>
        <Razlika>12</Razlika>
        <Procenat>13.00</Procenat>
      </JamFond>
    </Dio5JamFond>
  </Obrazac>
</XMLObrazac>
```

Comment: What program language? Why the xsd-tag?

Comment: Please show us your xml.

Comment: the .xsd file is now in the post as an update, the table was given only as an example but here is the real problem

Comment: Your screenshot does not make sense with the question - at all. Please update your question so sample resembles requirements. Also, you can post data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Help us help you.

Comment: @P.b I have updated my question. Hope you can help me now :)

Comment: I still don't see a data table. Please share some minimal reproduceable data and tell us what you need to. Also, what have you tried yourself? Also the ranges you refer to wanting to be mapped seem to be blank in your screenshot.

Comment: As for the data table I gave the screenshot of the Excel file, the relevant part. For the cells, they need to be blank and stay as I was given, I only have to map them, I mean my professor gave me like a test file where I can see how my output of the XML file needs to look like after mapping. I will put in the post screenshots of the result XML file

Comment: Please do not post XSD code as a screenshot, use plain text. Even if it's alot, StackOverflow will wrap the text in a scrollable code block.